# 'object' does not contain a definition error in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new in ASP.NET MVC.
I have a problem like below.
In Controller i have a code like this.

```
var students= db.Sagirdler.Where(x => x.SinifID == sinif.SinifID).
Select(m => new {m.Name, m.Surname}).ToList();

TempData["Students"] = students;

return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyPage");
```

This is my Index Action in MyPageController where I redirect and i call View.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        ViewBag.Students = TempData["Students"];
        return View();
}
```

And in View I use this code.

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  var students  = ViewBag.Students;
}
@foreach (var std in students)
{
   @std.Name
   <br/>
}
```

It says:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: `TempData` and `ViewBag` are not the same thing.

Comment: why are you not returning a model back to the view? why store it in TempData or ViewBag? Both are bad practices and you are defeating the purpose of MVC (M being the Model which gets passed to the V (View) to render on the page). I do see you are doing a RedirectToAction but are you redirecting to the same action? why? if different then are you sure you should be doing it where your code currently is?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use

```
ViewBag.Students = students;
```

instead of `TempData`.

What I think you're trying to achieve would be better implemented like so:

Create a class

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public string Name { get;set;}
    public string Surname {get;set;}
}
```

then in your view using

```
@model IEnumerable<StudentViewModel>

@foreach (var student in Model)
{
    ...
}
```

And in your controller

```
var students = db.Sagirdler.Where(x => x.SinifID == sinif.SinifID)
                 .Select(m => new StudentViewModel { Name = m.Name, Surname = m.Surname} )
                 .ToList();

return View(students);
```